# Binary search coming to error in tkinter gui python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, binary-search

This code is appearing to give me an error to my arguments i don't know what i have done wrong in this code. When attempting to run a binary search inside tkinter using python 2.7 The programs works fine if i don't use the gui just line code. This is the code I have based my program on

http://www.pythonschool.net/data-structures-algorithms/binary-search/

The error is:  Exception in Tkinter callback Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1536, in call return self.func(*args) TypeError: binarySearch() takes exactly 2 arguments (0 given)

```
from Tkinter import *
import csv

with open('scoresRecord.csv', 'rb') as f: 

reader = csv.reader(f) 
your_list = list(reader)

root = Tk()
root.resizable(0,0)
root.title("Score Board")


def binarySearch(myitem,myList):
found = False
bottom = 0
top = len(myList)-1
while bottom<=top and not found:
middle = (bottom+top)//2
if myList[middle]== myitem:
    found = True
elif myList[middle] < myitem:
    bottom = middle + 1
else:
    top = middle-1

return found




if __name__=="__main__":
    Scorelist = [row[0] for row in your_list]  
    Dismissallist =[row[1] for row in your_list] # create a list of only the          dismissal
    Venuelist =[row[2] for row in your_list] # create a list of only the venue
    item = int(input(entScore.get()))

    Scorelist = map(int, Scorelist)
    rowPos = Scorelist.index(item)
    isitFound = binarySearch(item,Scorelist)


if isitFound:
    Score= Scorelist[rowPos]
    Dismissal= Dismissallist[rowPos]
    Venue= Venuelist[rowPos]
else:
    Score= ("Not Found")
    Dismissal= ("Not Found")
    Venue= ("Not Found")



numScoreLbl.configure(text=Score)
numDismissal.configure(text=Dismissal)
outVenue.configure(text=Venue)


#==========GUI Section==================#
```

Comment: A good place to start would be to fix your indentation so that it actually matches the code you're running.  Indentation is crucial in Python, and what you've posted won't run at all.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure your list is ordered, otherwise the results may be wrong.

Second, do this

```
Scorelist = list(map(int, Scorelist))#convert to list
isitFound = binarySearch(item,Scorelist)
```

Although, if you are using .index method, then you can do something like this for better performance:

```
try:
    index = Scorelist.index(item)
    isitFound = True
except ValueError:
    isitFound = False
```

It takes out the binary search part, but you were using .index anyways. So this is better. Hope it helps :)